# Need to check for screenplay (Aziroazide azide)

Tags: warfare, chemistry

For a screenplay - I need to know if the following is possible; joining the components to make up Aziroazide azide from three separate lakes where the items exist pulled up to a mother ship where they are combined - my hope is that the C2N14 will be formed and thanks to its high instability destroy the mother ship. Is this plausible?

Comment: You'd probably have better luck in the chemistry stackexchange. By the way, aziroazide azide is a joke name if I refer to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/azidoazide_azide

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As pointed out in the previous comment, you are asking us if it is somehow possible to produce something which is only a joke in a blog. Can you clarify? Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to better understand this community,

Comment: @L.Dutch: The substance itself is not a joke. The *name* is a joke; the proper name of the substance in question is [1-diazidocarbamoyl-5-azidotetrazole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Diazidocarbamoyl-5-azidotetrazole). What the question asks if it is possible to find a way to produce it spontaneously from precursors. Unfortunately, there isn't. (Hint: the substance is an explosive. Its components very much prefer to be separate than together.)

Comment: @L.Dutch, did you delete my comment?  It's gone missing.

Comment: @JBH, that was an answer in comment. You are welcome to repost it where it belongs, once the issue on the name is solved

Comment: @L.Dutch, Ah.  It wasn't posted as an answer, but as a comment for clarification - but if that's the way you want to interpret it, no big deal.